# hibernate spring sigletons server down

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, singleton

I am using hibernate with spring frame work and my beans are in singleton mode.did i supposed to close my session or no (because they are in singleton mode)?
the reality is that we got some problems on our server and too many connections problem
and i thought may be that is the problem.thanks.

this is my codes:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" scope = "singleton" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref local="dataSource" property/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" >
        <value>Model.Entity</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

and this is the way i use , i close all sessions after i used

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void updateDB() {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code shouldn't bring down your server.

Comment: did i supposed to close the session or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the spring and hibernate configuration you don't need to close the connections and sessions, Spring will do that for you.
See this example http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/21/spring-3-and-hibernate-integration-tutorial-with-example/